# How to install Diamond XtremeSound 5.1. sound card driver for 12.04?

Tags: drivers

I bought a Diamond XtremeSound 5.1 sound card. I am looking for the driver for the sound card to install in Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Provide more information. Did you try it even yet? Ubuntu should detect it and use some driver for it. You might not have to install anything yourself.

Comment: This is apparently a rebadged C-Media CMI8738-LX, if that helps with the diagnosis process.

Answer (score 0):

The card isn't listed in the [ALSA support matrix](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-Diamond_Multimedia), so theoretically the card/chip isn't supported. But the [C-Media CMI8738-LX chip](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-C-Media) Oli mentioned is supported, at least the standard version is.

If you have a motherboard with a [HD-Audio specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_High_Definition_Audio) compliant controller, you wouldn't need [this card](https://www.diamondmm.com/xs51-diamond-xtremesound-sound-card.html). PCI is now being phased out and cannot be found on newer Intel motherboards. If you only have stereo out on your motherboard and you need 5.1 you should get a supported external USB soundcard. You can get the generic CM106 based ones from China or something from well known soundcard manufacturers like Asus and Creative (the recond3D USB worked out of the box when I tried) or more expensive ones from audio interface manufacturers.